# server client program arguments?

Tags: c, tcp, server, client

hello i was recently given this server/client program in c that is supposed to be okay and not have any mistakes. problem is every time i try to run it i get the message the program is supposed to print when there are not enough arguments (even though i give the port number and the message i want it to echo) could anyone help me find what i am doing wrong? thank you in advance for any help you give me. the code i wanna run is the following:

server :

```
#include <stdio.h> /* for printf() and fprintf() */
#include <sys/socket.h> /* for socket(), connect(), send(), and recv() */
#include <arpa/inet.h> /* for sockaddr_in and inet_addr() */
#include <stdlib.h> /* for atoi() */
#include <string.h> /* for memset() */
#include <unistd.h> /* for close() */

#define MAXPENDING 5 /* Maximum outstanding connection requests */
#define RCVBUFSIZE 32 /*Size of receive buffer*/

void DieWithError(char *errorMessage); /* Error handling function */
void HandleTCPClient(int clntSocket);/* TCP client handling function */


int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {


    int servSock; /* Socket descriptor for server */
    int clntSock; /* Socket descriptor for client */
    struct sockaddr_in echoServAddr; /* Local address */
    struct sockaddr_in echoClntAddr; /* Client address */
    unsigned short echoServPort; /* Server port */
    unsigned int clntLen; /* Length of client address data structure */

    if (argc != 2) {/* Test for correct number of arguments */
        fprintf(stderr, "Usage: %s <Server Port>\n", argv[0]) ;
        exit(1);
    }

    echoServPort = atoi(argv[1]); /* First arg: local port */

    /* Create socket for incoming connections */
    if ((servSock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP)) < 0)
        DieWithError( "socket () failed") ;

    /* Construct local address structure */
    memset(&echoServAddr, 0, sizeof(echoServAddr)); /* Zero out structure */
    echoServAddr.sin_family = AF_INET; /* Internet address family */
    echoServAddr.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY); /* Any incoming interface */
    echoServAddr.sin_port = htons(echoServPort); /* Local port */

    /* Bind to the local address */
    if (bind(servSock, (struct sockaddr *)&echoServAddr, sizeof(echoServAddr)) < 0)
        DieWithError ( "bind () failed");

    /* Mark the socket so it will listen for incoming connections */
    if (listen(servSock, MAXPENDING) < 0)
        DieWithError("listen() failed") ;

    for (;;) {/* Run forever */

        /* Set the size of the in-out parameter */
        clntLen = sizeof(echoClntAddr);

        /* Wait for a client to connect */
        if ((clntSock = accept(servSock, (struct sockaddr *) &echoClntAddr, &clntLen)) < 0)
            DieWithError("accept() failed");

        /* clntSock is connected to a client! */
        printf("Handling client %s\n", inet_ntoa(echoClntAddr.sin_addr));
        HandleTCPClient (clntSock) ;
    }
    /* NOT REACHED */
}

void DieWithError(char *errorMessage){

    perror(errorMessage);
    exit(1);
}


void HandleTCPClient(int clntSocket) {

    char echoBuffer[RCVBUFSIZE];/* Buffer for echo string */
    int recvMsgSize;/* Size of received message */


    /* Receive message from client */
    if ((recvMsgSize = recv(clntSocket, echoBuffer, RCVBUFSIZE, 0)) < 0)
        DieWithError("recv() failed") ;

    /* Send received string and receive again until end of transmission */
    while (recvMsgSize > 0){ /* zero indicates end of transmission */

        /* Echo message back to client */
        if (send(clntSocket, echoBuffer, recvMsgSize, 0) != recvMsgSize)
            DieWithError("send() failed");

        /* See if there is more data to receive */
        if ((recvMsgSize = recv(clntSocket, echoBuffer, RCVBUFSIZE, 0)) < 0)
            DieWithError("recv() failed") ;

    }
    close(clntSocket); /* Close client socket */
}
```

the client is the following:

```
#include <stdio.h> /* for printf() and fprintf() */
#include <sys/socket.h> /* for socket(), connect(), send(), and recv() */
#include <arpa/inet.h> /* for sockaddr_in and inet_addr() */
#include <stdlib.h> /* for atoi() */
#include <string.h> /* for memset() */
#include <unistd.h> /* for close() */

#define RCVBUFSIZE 32 /* Size of receive buffer */

void DieWithError(char *errorMessage); /* Error handling function */

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

    int sock; /* Socket descriptor */
    struct sockaddr_in echoServAddr; /* Echo server address */
    unsigned short echoServPort; /* Echo server port */
    char *servIP; /* Server IP address (dotted quad) */
    char *echoString; /* String to send to echo server */
    char echoBuffer[RCVBUFSIZE]; /* Buffer for echo string */
    unsigned int echoStringLen; /* Bytes read in single recv()*/
    int bytesRcvd, totalBytesRcvd; /*total bytes read */

    if ((argc<3) || (argc>4)) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Usage: %s <Server IP> <Echo Word> [<Echo Port>]\n", argv[0]);
        exit(1);
    }
    servIP = argv[1] ; /* First arg' server IP address (dotted quad) */
    echoString = argv[2] ;/* Second arg' string to echo */


    if (argc == 4)
        echoServPort = atoi(argv[3]); /* Use given port, if any */
    else
        echoServPort = 7; /* 7 is the well-known port for the echo service */

    /* Create a reliable, stream socket using TCP */
    if ((sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP)) < 0)
        DieWithError(" socket () failed") ;

    /* Construct the server address structure */
    memset(&echoServAddr, 0, sizeof(echoServAddr)); /* Zero out structure */
    echoServAddr.sin_family = AF_INET; /* Internet address family */
    echoServAddr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr(servIP); /* Server IP address */
    echoServAddr.sin_port = htons(echoServPort); /* Server port */

    /* Establish the connection to the echo server */
    if (connect(sock, (struct sockaddr *) &echoServAddr, sizeof(echoServAddr)) < 0)
        DieWithError(" connect () failed") ;

    echoStringLen = strlen(echoString) ; /* Determine input length */

    /* Send the string to the server */
    if (send(sock, echoString, echoStringLen, 0) != echoStringLen)
        DieWithError("send() sent a different number of bytes than expected");

    /* Receive the same string back from the server */
    totalBytesRcvd = 0;
    printf("Received: "); /* Setup to print the echoed string */
    while (totalBytesRcvd < echoStringLen) {
    /* Receive up to the buffer size (minus 1 to leave space for
        a null terminator) bytes from the sender */
        if ((bytesRcvd = recv(sock, echoBuffer, RCVBUFSIZE - 1, 0)) <= 0)
            DieWithError("recv() failed or connection closed prematurely");
        totalBytesRcvd += bytesRcvd; /* Keep tally of total bytes */
        echoBuffer[bytesRcvd] = '\0'; /* Terminate the string! */
        printf(echoBuffer); /* Print the echo buffer */
    }
    printf("\n"); /* Print a final linefeed */

    close(sock);
    exit(0);
}

void DieWithError(char *errorMessage){

    perror(errorMessage);
    exit(1);
}
```

Comment: Make sure you put the message in quotes.

Comment: Your problem is not clear: you try to run the server, the client. When did you get an error message?

Answer (score 0):

Correct me if I'm wrong, but I assume the problem is that you are inputting the wrong parameters, and are getting the "Usage: ..." error message?

Provided you compile it correctly, the programs should run with something like the following commands:

./server 1200

./client localhost message 1200

The server program accepts only 1 parameter, and the client program accepts 2 or 3 parameters. The server should also be run before the client.